# Dompdf characters enconfing utf-8 destroy document

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

i have problem with UTF-8 enconding in dompdf
after i found the solution i'm added this lines :

in the html section

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
*{ font-family: DejaVu Sans; font-size: 12px;}
```

and also add this in php section

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dompdf->loadHtml($content);
```

Now the content is looking like :

[image]

Comment: I would wager that your content is corrupted before it even hits `mb_convert_encoding()`.

Comment: Ignoring the PDF for a bit, if you viewed the rendered HTML generated by the `mb_convert_encoding`, does it look okay?

Comment: if i return html code - look ok. only after parsing is looking soo :(

Comment: Can you provide a fuller example of your HTML? For example, are you calling both the output and stream methods? Doing so triggers a known issue that corrupts the output.

Answer (score -1):

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dompdf->loadHtml(utf8_encode($content));
```

Comment: can you improve you answer so people can understand